# How can I get EaselJS's MouseEvent to work properly? It SEEMS to work, but it keeps returning back a single bitmap ID, not the correct

Tags: javascript, bitmap, mouseevent, easeljs

I'm writing a mini-game in EaselJS that requires mouse clicks on a grid of tiles. 
However, it appears that it's only partially working - or perhaps not assigning a unique Event to each bitmap. During creation, I assign a simple ID - a number counting up per iteration, and expect to get that back.... but no matter where I click, out of 49 objects on stage (hexagon tiles), it only reports back 48....every time. I have enabled stage.enableMouseOver(20), which I initially forgot, but it did not help.

```
function BuildGround()
{
    var i = 0;
    for (var x = 0; x < 7; x++)
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < 7; y++)
        {

            var h = 102;
            var s = h/Math.cos(30*Math.PI/180)/2;


            var tempTile = new createjs.Sprite(Tiles, 0);
            WorldContainer.addChild(tempTile);          
            tempTile.regX = 64;
            tempTile.regY = 64;

            tempTile.id = i;

            tempTile.x = x * s * 1.5;
            tempTile.y = y * h + (x % 2) * h / 2;

            tempTile.addEventListener("click", function(event) { alert(tempTile.id); })

            TileArray.push(tempTile);
            i++;

            console.log(i);
        }
    }

    WorldContainer.x = 155;
    WorldContainer.y = 150;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, you are experiencing context problem of JavaScript, try this:

```
tempTile.addEventListener("click", function(event) { alert(event.target.id); })
```

All events objects have a target element, usually the one which triggered it.

Comment: Thank you for offering an answer... as it turns out through bandwith testing, it's not really viable for me to run this HTML5 game version. Twelve hours of stress testing generated over a gig of bandwith, so now looking for another solution.